# Qt 4.8 Qtransform for rotating qgraphicsitem

Tags: c++, qt, rotation

I have rotated the qgraphicsitem (say rectangle) using `QTransform::translate(x, y).rotate(angle).translate(-x, -y)`.

Before applying rotation, boundingrect() gives the correct bounding rectangle of item.

After applying rotation using `QTransform`, it gives the previous bounding rectangle when `boundingrect()` or `sceneboundingrect()` called. i.e. not rotated rectangle.

I have tried using `boundingRegion` etc still not giving the correct bounding rectangle after rotation. Incremental rotation gives previous bounding rectangle instead of current bounding rectangle.

Also, how to check the that item (specially when `QTransform` applied i.e. rotate, scale etc) is not within the scene rectangle?

Thanks in Advance,
Regards

Comment: Why do you don't use QGraphicsItem::setRotation method?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply... setRotation() continously calls paint() function... Will check this option by adding check for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you wouldn't expect boundingrect() to change because it is always expressed in [Item Coordinates](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html#item-coordinates).

I have an idea that you may need to call [prepareGeometryChange()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#prepareGeometryChange) at some point for this sort of stuff to properly updated (ie for the sceneTransform and consequently sceneBoundingRect to return correct values).

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply.. I Have tried prepareGeometryChange() and update functions after applying rotation. Still it gives the previous rectangle instead of current rectangle. Also wrote function to return bounding rect after rotation but same result as above...